# combobox editor of gridcolumn issue

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4

[image: error image]

Whenever I choose an item from the combobox, the combobox goes up on the screen. It only disappear when I move on the second column or do anything. It is quite annoying. How do I make it fixed on the grid? Is this a bug? Here is my code:

```
{
                                header: "Description",
                                sortable: false,
                                width: 250,
                                renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
                                editor: new Ext.form.field.ComboBox( {
                                    enableKeyEvents:true,
                                    typeAhead: true,
                                    typeAheadDelay: 100,
                                    queryMode: 'local',
                                    forceSelection: true,
                                    selectOnTab: true,
                                    queryDelay : 100,
                                    store : aob_store_inventory, 
                                    valueField: 'InvDescription', 
                                    displayField: 'InvDescription',
                                    triggerAction: 'all',
                                    editable : true,
                                    listeners: {
                                        select: function(combo, record, index) {
                                            store_aobdetails.data.items[aob_sel_rec].data.InvID = record[0].data.InvID;
                                            store_aobdetails.commitChanges();
                                            combo.up('grid').getView().refresh();
                                        }
                                    }
                                }),
                                dataIndex: 'InvDescription'
                            }
```

Comment: Are you using CellEditing plugin? http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.0.7/#!/api/Ext.grid.plugin.CellEditing

Answer (score 0):

fixed it by removing the code:

```
combo.up('grid').getView().refresh();
```